# C, string input without spaces or tabs

Tags: c, string, input, dynamic, malloc

I am trying to find the best way of getting an input of string without the spaces and tabs.

And from it to get dynamic number of the individual strings that the main one contian.

For example:
For the string str = "    abc  \t tt    6  \t   4 7" 
(There can be a lot more spaces and tabs between the individual strings)

The out put will be str1 = "abc" str2 = "tt" str3 = "6" str4 = "4" str5 = "7"

I thought maybe for the dynamic creation of string to use malloc to creat an array of strings. But I could not make it work, and ignore the spaces and tabs (\t)

Comment: Are you aware of `strtok()`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok The example code seems 99% of what you want.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the strtok() fuction I tried to use it but I needed to use the more secure and new function strtok_s, but I didnt mange to use 2 delim (the spaces and the tabs \t) can you pls give a working example of it with 2 delim? @Yunnosch

Comment: Just use `" \t"` as (set of) delimiters to `strtok()`.

Comment: Which documentation to `strtok()` did you read?

Comment: The reference is here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.8

Comment: I can recommend the documentation I linked, it covers the meaning of the parameter `delim` for both, `strtok()` and `strtok_s()`.

Comment: `strtok_r()` isn't C but POSIX, So it's documentation is here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html

Comment: @Yunnosch: "*it covers the meaning of the parameter delim for ***both***" Isn't it the same for "*both*"? ;-)

Comment: @alk Yes, just to prevent the misunderstanding that it is only talking about strtok().

Comment: @alk Your `strtok_r()` is a typo? Does not look like OP is mentioning it...

Comment: @Yunnosch: `strtok_s` is Windowsish for `strtok_r` which is POSIXish. They are the same, I think.

Comment: @Yunnosch: To add some more confusion to this we have C11 Appendix K defining another `strtok_s()` (which naturellement is different from the Windows one): http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.7.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look to  strtok() and strtok_r() functions from string.h

It allows you to split a string by specifying which characters are delimiters.